# Disable Users in a csv file by employee number and then move into certain OU

Tags: csv, powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to compare a list of terminated employees to the AD attribute EmployeeNumber.

When I run the code below it appears that it only returns null for each employee number.

I receive the error for each user:

> User does not exist in AD

**What am I doing wrong with the compare?**

```
$file = Import-CSV  Term.csv
foreach ($u in $file) {
  $user = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "EmployeeNumber -eq $($u.Emp)"
  If ($user -eq $Null) {
    "User does not exist in AD   " + $u.EmployeeName + " - " + $u.Emp
  } Else {
    Disable-ADAccount $user
    Move-ADObject $user -TargetPath 'OU=Disabled Users,OU=Org Users,DC=Company,Dc=com'
    Set-ADUser $user -Description "Account Disabled on $(get-date)"
  }
}
```

Comment: try changing `-LDAPFilter` to `-Filter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Get-ADUser` command is using the `LDAPFilter` parameter, but not using LDAP Filtering syntax in it.  You have two options here, change the parameter to `-Filter` or change the filtering sytax.

## Get-ADUser -Filter

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeNumber -eq $($u.Emp)"
```

## Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(EmployeeNumber=$($u.Emp))"
```